# How do we predict the motion of this systems using Newton's laws of Motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, conservation-laws, free-body-diagram

This question should be seen as an argument for these Answers. I want you to read the answers to this following question before answering it.

[Violating Newtons First Law!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/449699/)

Here Everybody is saying CM of the whole system will be at rest. But I want to argue on this matter by asking you two things?

1. Assume an elephant is inside this box. When that elephant moves inside the box, will it change the position of the centre of mass of the whole system, the mass distribution is changing with time? Can I argue that C.M is in acceleration?
2. If the elephant makes a fart inside the box, Will the box move if the platform has some friction.

Comment: How can the COM move if no net external force acts on the system?

Answer (score 0):

1. In space with no external gravity or friction, if the elephant is on one side of the box, the COM will be at a certain point, not in the center of the box but off center towards the heavier elephant, if the elephant pushes on the box, the box will move one direction and the elephant will move in the opposite direction until it hits the other side of the box. If it grabs the opposite wall and does not bounce off, then the box and the elephant will both stop. Now the elephant is more one way and the box is more the other way in relation to the COM, but the COM has not moved.
   2.If the box is no longer in space, but on a platform on Earth with friction, it is doubtful the elephant's gas will overcome external friction.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you (the elephant)  are inside the box and the box is in space. the center of mass (COM) is depending on your mass (m) the box mass (M) and the mass  distance (a and b) to the COM. the position vector to the COM is:

$$\vec{R}_{com}=\frac{m\,a+M\,b}{m+M}$$

If we put our coordinate system at the COM ,thus

$$\vec{R}_{com}=0\quad \Rightarrow\,m\,a+M\,b=0$$

so at beginning of our experiment  we have static equilibrium

now you begin to move inside the box to see what's happened look at the free body diagram (II) and the equations of motions at the COM:

$$ (m+M)\ddot{x}=F_\mu$$
$$\ddot{y}=-g$$
$$I_{com}\ddot{\varphi}=F_\mu\,h+\underbrace{m\,g\,a+M\,g\,b}_{=0}$$

with $F_\mu=\mu\,m\,g$ the friction force and $I_{com}$ the inertial at the COM.

Thus:

the COM  will move ,relative to the inertial system, to the right (x-direction )  free falling in y-direction   and rotate about the COM  ($\varphi$-direction).

The "position" of the COM in the box is unchanged!

**Remark:**

the equations of motion are given  in inertial system not in body fixed system

Answer (score 0):

A very brief answer would be **The centre of mass of the system was initially at rest and will remain at rest because linear momentum of the whole system is conserved in both of the cases asked by you**.